# Derivatives of a spline: `scipy splev`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to find derivatives of a spline at several points using `splev` in `scipy`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function to normalize each row
def normalized(a, axis=-1, order=2):
    l2 = np.atleast_1d(np.linalg.norm(a, order, axis))
    l2[l2==0] = 1
    return a / np.expand_dims(l2, axis)

# points and spline
pts = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,np.sqrt(2)],[4,2],[9,3]])
tck, u = splprep(pts.T, u=None, k=3, s=0.0, per=0)

# compute new points and derivatives
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 5*u.shape[0])
x_new, y_new = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)
xp_num, yp_num = splev(pts, tck, der=1) # numerical derivatices
xp_the, yp_the= pts[1:,0], 0.5/np.sqrt(pts[1:,0]) # analytical derivatives
R = normalized(yp_num/xp_num)
X,Y = pts[1:,0], pts[1:,1]
U,V = X + R[1:,0], Y+R[1:,1]
```

I'd like to plot the tangents at the given point:

```
plt.plot(x_new,y_new,'-b')
plt.plot(pts[:,0],pts[:,1],'--ro')
plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy')
```

[image]

I think these tangent lines are wrong. My understanding was that `xp_num` and `yp_num` are numerical derivatives of the spline with respect to `x` and `y`. So to find `dy/dx`, I should simply divide them. Is this correct?

Eventually, I'd like to find tangents of a curve like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464345/fitting-a-closed-curve-to-a-set-of-points)

Comment: what does `normalized` do?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: It normalizes each row. I added the definition of `normalize`.

Comment: Strange, your code looks to me as if it shouldn't create any vectors in the plot at all. `yp_num` and `xp_num` are 1d, aren't they? So your `R` should be 1 x something, so when you are slicing `R[1:,0] you should get an empty array. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PaulPanzer: The shape of `yp_num` and `xp_num` is `(5,2)` which confuses me!

Comment: Of, course, that's the bug! You are passing pts as the first parameter to splev, which is complete and utter nonsense!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem (the obviously wrong derivatives) is not related to the numerical derivative since you are not using them at least in the code you posted. What is clearly wrong unless your `normalized` function does something truly magic is your dividing `yp_the` by `xp_the` since the former is indeed the increment, the latter is not it should be constant to get

```
dy
--
dx
```

as opposed to your

```
 dy
----
x dx
```

You were probably coming from the formula for a parametric curve

```
.     dy
      --
dy    dt
-- = ----
dx    dx
      --
      dt
```

used `t=x` and then overlooked that `dx/dx` is constant. Kind of thing that happens to the best of us.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly right I thought about parametric curve! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you didn't include your `R = normalized(yp_the/xp_the)` source

I did it with linalg.norm

then I changed the delta_Y for the normalized derivative

and gave up on quiver

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splprep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# points and spline
pts = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,np.sqrt(2)],[4,2],[9,3]])
tck, u = splprep(pts.T, u=None, k=3, s=0.0, per=0)

# compute new points and derivatives
u_new = np.linspace(u.min(), u.max(), 5*u.shape[0])
x_new, y_new = splev(u_new, tck, der=0)
xp_num, yp_num = splev(pts, tck, der=1) # numerical derivatices
xp_the, yp_the= pts[1:,0], 0.5/np.sqrt(pts[1:,0]) # analytical derivatives
#R = normalized(yp_the/xp_the)
N = np.linalg.norm(np.array([xp_the, yp_the]), axis=0)

X,Y = pts[1:,0], pts[1:,1]
#U,V = X + R[1:,0], Y+R[1:,1]
U,V = X + xp_the/N, Y + X*yp_the/N # delta Y = dy/dx * x

plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

plt.plot(x_new,y_new,'-b')
plt.plot(pts[:,0],pts[:,1],'--ro')
#plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V, scale=10, pivot='mid')# angles='xy', scale_units=’xy’, scale=1

plt.plot((X, U), (Y, V), '-k', lw=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry about my mistake. I meant to plot the tangents using `xp_num` and `yp_num`.