# Cubic spline interpolation on closed loops

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I have some data which in an x-y plane is a closed loop. I want to do a cubic spline interpolation between the points I have (which are pairs of (x,y)). I mainly need the first and second derivatives at the points I have, and a cubic spline will give me that. I tried using scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline, however this doesn't work when the x values are not in increasing order (and in my case, given than I have a loop, they are not). How can I do the interpolation in this case? Thank you!

Comment: could you provide any code you have tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fitting a closed curve to a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464345/fitting-a-closed-curve-to-a-set-of-points)