# Curve Fitting to Scattered Data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# Function to calculate distance between two points
def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2)

# Read points from file
points = []
with open("coord.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        x, y = map(int, line.strip().split())
        points.append((x, y))

# Initialize lists to store connected points and points yet to connect
connected_points = [points[0]]
points_to_connect = points[1:]

# Connect the nearest point until all points are connected
while points_to_connect:
    # Find the nearest point to the last connected point
    last_point = connected_points[-1]
    nearest_point = min(points_to_connect, key=lambda p: distance(last_point, p))
    
    # Move the nearest point from points_to_connect to connected_points
    points_to_connect.remove(nearest_point)
    connected_points.append(nearest_point)

# Plotting points and connecting them with lines
plt.scatter(*zip(*points), color='red')  # Plots the points
for i in range(len(connected_points) - 1):  # Connects the points with a line
    plt.plot(*zip(*connected_points[i:i+2]), color='blue')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Connecting Nearest Points')

# Showing the plot
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

to connect the points for which I have coordinates. The code works perfectly for some coordinate files, but doesn't work for the coordinates that I need, it misses a point and connects the point to the very first point.

What I want to do, is to have code that reads a text file that has three columns, plots the data in the second column vs. the third column, and connects each two consecutive points to each other. I want to make a curve with a set of points.
My data looks like this: the second and third column are coordinates of points (which are output from another simulation)

(0 149.68752602446622  60.31434186400232)
(0 149.69331627188203  65.34321553470865)
(0 149.7019081389601     70.37384784896992)

Can anyone please help me with this? The code works very well for a coordinate set that has an integer value.
I also tried the solution here: [Fitting a closed curve to a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464345/fitting-a-closed-curve-to-a-set-of-points)

But still have the same problem.

two snaps of the plots are attached for reference.

[image: whole image]
[image: corrupted part]

Comment: You are explicitly converting all values into integers when you read them in with the line `x, y = map(int, line.strip().split())`. Change the `int` to `float` to have them as floating point numbers.

Comment: Thank you, but that one point is still missing. And I have this problem for this set of data. The code works very well for another set of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
last_point = connected_points[-1]
```

You're assuming the last point of "coord.txt" is also the last point of the curve, but maybe isn't. (I don't have the data so I'm not sure)

[image]

Maybe your algorithm is starting from the black circle (last point of the file txt) and connect all the points following the red arrows.

What you can do is check the points following this sequence:

0. Select a point you want to study
1. Find the nearest point from the point in step 0
2. Find the second nearest point from the point in step 0
3. If the point in step 2 is closer to the point in step 1 rather than the point in step 0 then you find the tail of the curve (or the point from where you want to start connecting points)