# making a closed curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a set of data which looks like below:

```
0.0,0.1,0.0
0.0,0.09987714877467492,0.005050556279843527

0.0,0.09980450443077922,0.010092681565644489

0.0,0.09975499879273926,0.015109690654306573

0.0,0.09971073675921141,0.02012768105094637

0.0,0.0996747741672319,0.025141279807181033

0.0,0.0996853457866208,0.09532893107285735
```

I want to plot the third column vs the second column, connect each two consecutive points, and make a closed curve. I can plot the third column vs the second, but the codes I try to connect them, the result is not what I'm looking for. A figure is attached as a reference.
The code I'm using is

```
# Function to read points from file, focusing on the second and third columns
def read_points(filename):
    points = []
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            _, x, y = line.strip().split(',')
            points.append((float(x), float(y)))
    return points

# Read points from the file
points = read_points("Entrance.dat")

# Plotting points and connecting them with lines
plt.scatter(*zip(*points), color='red')  # Plots the points
plt.plot(*zip(*points), color='blue')    # Connects the points with a line to form a curve

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Curve from Data Points')

# Showing the plot
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Can you please help me in the correct direction? there is any link I could look into? I saw this page:
[Fitting a closed curve to a set of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464345/fitting-a-closed-curve-to-a-set-of-points)

But it doesn't help me.

[image: the curve]
The issue withe curve is that it connects the points to each other with no respect to the order.

Comment: plt.plot connects the dots in the order they have in the list - it is not what you want but it is predictable. It does that because it makes sense for your typical (x -> y)-graphs

Comment: you could order the points to minimize the total distance of the path before putting it in the plot. That would be a Traveling Salesman Problem and there must be some implementations of solutions online

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the future you can also be interested in using a more sophisticated library like [`shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) for this kind of problems. Broadly speaking, `shapely` is a Python library that allows you to manipulate planar objects, for instance polygons.

You can install `shapely` with the following command:

```bash
pip install shapely
```

or if you are using conda:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge shapely
```

Then you can create a polygon given the coordinates you have provided as below:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely import Polygon

data = [
    (0.0, 0.09987714877467492, 0.005050556279843527),
    (0.0, 0.09980450443077922, 0.010092681565644489),
    (0.0, 0.09975499879273926, 0.015109690654306573),
    (0.0, 0.09971073675921141, 0.02012768105094637),
    (0.0, 0.0996747741672319, 0.025141279807181033),
    (0.0, 0.0996853457866208, 0.09532893107285735)
]

data = np.array(data)[:, 1:]
polygon = Polygon(data)
```

Then you can plot it:

```py
coordinates = np.column_stack(polygon.exterior.xy)
plt.plot(coordinates[:, 0], coordinates[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The nice thing is that you have now access to a lot of useful attributes such as the area or the centroid of the polygon:

```py
print(polygon.area)
print(polygon.centroid)
```